# One-lined legend (Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to have the legend on top of my plot to be single-lined. I tried to use `guide_legend(nrow=1)` and `guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=1,byrow=TRUE))` which both produce the same error `Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot`

**Example image**

[image]

This is my code and data:

```
date = as.Date(c("2015-06-09","2015-06-09","2015-06-09","2015-06-09","2015-06-09","2015-06-09","2015-06-09, 2015-06-10","2015-06-10","2015-06-10","2015-06-10","2015-06-10","2015-06-10","2015-06-10","2015-06-10"))
ph = c(8.1, 7.66, 6.71, 8.23, 8.23, 8.21, 7.9,8.1, 7.66, 6.71, 8.23, 8.23, 8.21, 7.9)
step = c("Step1","Step2","Step3","Step4","Step5","Step6","Step7","Step1","Step2","Step3","Step4","Step5","Step6","Step7")

df = data.frame(date,ph,step)

df_plot <- ggplot(df,aes(x=date, y=ph, group=step,color=step, shape=step)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) + geom_point(size=2) + geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") + guide_legend(nrow=1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I can't test it right now, but can you try use `theme(legend.position = "top", legend.box = "horizontal")` and tell me if it works?

Comment: You have colour and shape aesthetics, so those are what you need to set in `guides`: `guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=TRUE), shape=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=TRUE))` (although I don't think `byrow` changes anything here). `guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=TRUE))` shouldn't produce an error, but won't change the plot in any way.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks for your response. Your solution works perfectly fine!

Comment: @Mutador Thanks for your response. I tried that before and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can put guide_legend() inside scale_shape_manual(). The following worked for me:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=date, y=ph, group=step,color=step, shape=step)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), guide = guide_legend(nrow=1)) +
    geom_point(size=2) + geom_line() +
    theme(legend.position = "top")
```